# Does the “-s” change the word class of “it”?

Tags: suffixes, parts-of-speech, derivational-morphology, inflectional-morphology

The word **it** is a pronoun. When I add an **s** to it, does it change the word class?

For example in the following sentence:

> *The gift is still in **its** box.*

My questions are:

> 1. Does the "S" change the word class?
> 2. Is the "S" an inflectional or derivational morpheme?

Comment: Please allow several hours or even better, a couple of days, before accepting an answer.

Comment: See also [linguistics.se]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Its** is in your first example the possessive determiner of the personal pronoun **it**. See this page by [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns/pronouns-possessive-my-mine-your-yours-etc), which states the following about it:

> personal pronoun: it
>
> possessive determiner: its
>
> possessive pronoun: its (this one is rarely used)

The added **s** is not an inflectional affix (unless one would treat **it** as a noun), because [there are only 8 in the English language](http://nagelhout.faculty.unlv.edu//ENG411Bs12C/mod1concept2.html) and those 8 do not correspond with this one. If **it** is seen as a noun, it could be argued that the added **s** is a noun possessive, which is one of the 8 *inflectional affixes* listed on that page.

According to [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_morpheme) **it** (and other pronouns) is (are) a functional morpheme(s).

Comment: So, it did change the word's class? Which makes it derivational , right? –

Comment: EDIT: I meant to say "derivational morpheme " but the auto correction missed it up. Sorry

Comment: @mathlearner I am not entirely sure about that, it could be, but I really don't know.

Comment: No problem, Thank you so much. You have been a great help!

Comment: The linked page says "noun possessive {-s}" is an inflectional affix. Are you saying that the *s* in "its" is not the same as in the *'s* in something like "Sally's"?

Comment: @sumelic is **it**  in this case considered a noun?

Comment: @JJJ: Some people treat pronouns as a subset of nouns.

Comment: @sumelic I see, I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: Before reading this answer I was thinking "possessive pronoun". Then I got to thinking about contexts like *I've only got one plate for me and one for the dog. So you'll have to eat off **its**.* As you say, "rarely used".

Answer (score 1):

This is just a supplement to the excellent answer by sumelic.

For completeness:

1. No, adding an 's' to 'it' to produce 'its' does not result in a change in class. Both *it* and *its* are pronouns.
2. This 's' is an inflectional morpheme.

**Discussion**

Both [CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468) and [ComGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0582517346) would say that *its* is just the pronoun *it* in the **genitive case**. And as far as what 'case' is, according to CGEL (p. 455),

> The term case applies in the first instance to a system of inflectional forms of a noun that serve to mark the function of an NP relative to the construction containing it.

(CGEL treats pronouns as a subcategory of nouns, whereas ComGEL does not; if you don't want to take pronouns as a subcategory of nouns, just replace *of a noun* in the above by *of a noun or a pronoun*.)

These two grammars do not use the term 'inflectional morpheme', but from the above, it follows that 's' in *its* is precisely that.

Answer (score 1):

The VERB *walk* inflects according to
*case* > he walk**s**
*tense* > he walk**ed**
*aspect* >he is walk**ing**

The  NOUN *walk* is inflected to denote the

*plural* > He enjoyed his Sunday *walk**s***
*genetive* > Click on the [***walk’s*** name](https://www.southwestcoastpath.org.uk/walk-coast-path/days-out/easy-access-walks/easy-access-north-cornwall/) (note the apostrophe)

> Inflection is the process of adding inflectional morphemes that **modify a verb's tense or a noun's number**, rarely affecting the word's meaning or class. Examples of applying inflectional morphemes to words are adding -s to the root *dog* to form dogs and adding -ed to *wait* to form waited.

Sometimes a **[derivational morpheme](https://www.thoughtco.com/derivational-morpheme-words-1690381)** is added to modify the meaning
*agent noun* > a walk**er** (either a person who walks, or a walking frame)

> In contrast, derivation is the process of adding **derivational morphemes, which create a new word from existing words and change the semantic meaning or the part of speech** of the affected word, such as by changing a noun to a verb

Sometimes the suffix -er is an **[inflectional morpheme](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-an-inflectional-morpheme-1691064)**, the -er is attached to monosyllabic ADJECTIVES to form its comparative. For example, *hotter* tells us that something has a higher temperature, and we use the  suffix -est to form the superlative (*hottest*), the adjective *hot* remains an adjective even when the suffixes -er and -est are used.

The possessive PRONOUN **its** is always spelled *its*.  When an apostrophe is added, i.e. *it's*, it changes meaning to represent the contracted form of  *it is* or *it has*.

The plural form of *it* is not *its*. Similarly, we don't normally say *Is*, *yous*, *hes*, or *shes*, instead their plural equivalents are:  *we*, *you* and *they*. The possessive adjectives: *your*, *her* and *their* are the only ones which accept an -s suffix, while the POSSESSIVE ADJECTIVE / PRONOUN *his* and *its* remain unchanged, e.g.
A: *Whose is this cover?*
B: “It's your**s**/her**s**/his (no change)/their**s**”
B: “It's it**s**” (grammatical but rather awkward to say the least.)

> **"Only English nouns, verbs, adjectives, and adverbs**–all open classes of words–**take inflectional affixes**. Closed classes of words . . . take no inflectional affixes in English. Inflectional affixes always follow derivational ones if both occur in a word, which makes sense if we think of inflections as affixes on fully formed words. For example, the words *antidisestablishmentarianism* and *uncompartmentalize* each contain a number of derivational affixes, and any inflectional affixes must occur at the end: *antidisestablishmentarianism**s*** and *uncompartmentalize**d***.
>
> (Kristin Denham and Anne Lobeck, Linguistics for Everyone. Wadsworth, 2010)

See also Wikipedia's article on *[Inflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection#Compared_to_derivation)*

Answer (score 0):

The word *it* is a pronoun<sup>1</sup>. The word *its* is also a pronoun<sup>2</sup>. So the word class is the same.

The *s* is an inflectional morpheme, like the *'s* used in the spelling of the possessive form *Sally's* of the noun *Sally.* In fact, although the spelling is different in standard English, it could be argued that the *s* in *its* is the same inflectional morpheme as *'s.* In more abstract analyses, the same morpheme might even be considered to be present in words like *her* and *my* despite the completely different phonological realization: the idea that one morpheme may have completely different phonological realizations in different words is an extreme example of the concept of "allomorphy". The extended version of this concept is often illustrated with the example of English plurals: some people argue that even though there are several distinct ways of marking the plural forms of nouns in English from a phonological perspective, all plural nouns can be considered to contain the same plural morpheme (variably realized as things like /z/, /s/ /ɪz/, ∅, /ən/, ...). You can see a more extensive description of this in the following presentation: http://ling.uni-konstanz.de/pages/home/plank/for_download/SHE-I-WS11-12/2-Allomorphy.pdf

Even if you  don't use this conception of allomorphy, it's still clear that *its* is an inflected, not a derived form of *it.* You can see pronoun forms described as inflections in "[Cases, Inflection, and Pronouns](http://www.jebbo.co.uk/learn-oe/ch2.htm)" by Tony Jebson.

---

1. Note that [pronouns may be considered a subcategory of nouns](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/316726/are-pronouns-nouns) (pronouns obviously don't behave the same as either proper nouns or common nouns, but that can be explained in terms of pronouns not sharing the properties that are specific to these other subsets of nouns, rather than pronouns not sharing the properties that are characteristic of the overarching category of nouns.)
2. Some people call words like *my your its* "possessive adjectives" or "possessive determiners" rather than "possessive pronouns", reserving the latter term for words like *mine yours,* but there are several arguments for considering both sets of words to be pronouns. Forms like *her his its* can take previously-mentioned nouns as antecedents; they can also be used as the subject of the non-finite *-ing* form of a verb (at least for some speakers--there are some speakers who apparently think that this construction sounds strange in many contexts).

Comment: Note that the two highest voted answers in that post say "pronouns differ inflectionally from prototypical nouns". I am not sure if that changes anything regarding extending this property (of inflectional morphemes) of nouns to pronouns.

Comment: @JJJ: Right; but the answers don't say that pronouns don't inflect, just that they inflect differently from other nouns.

Comment: Thank you so much. That is the greatest explanation. I really wish my instructor explains things this way.

Comment: Usually *its* is a possessive determiner like *my*, but sometimes it’s a possessive pronoun like *mine*. (Or maybe that should read: ... but sometimes *its*’s a possessive pronoun like *mine* :)

Comment: @tchrist: As I said in the second note, there are reasons to consider *my* a pronoun. "Determiner" is a function, not a part of speech. The name *Sally* is a proper noun, and we presumably don't want to say that it changes its part of speech when we form a phrase like *Sally's house.*

Comment: In case you didn't know, only one vote is needed to reopen the question.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Unfortunately, I’m one of the existing four...

Comment: Pity, the reopen queue has shut down. I might bring it up on meta, if I have the time to spare.... maybe if you edited the question (is there something that can be fixed?) that will bump it to the front page.