# Can 'pronouns' be considered ad hoc proper nouns?

Tags: terminology, pronouns, proper-nouns

The term 'pronoun' itself causes plenty of confusion.

[Its etymology](https://www.etymonline.com/word/pronoun) suggests that a pronoun somehow stands for a noun:

> mid-15c., from pro- and noun; modeled on Middle French pronom, from Latin pronomen, from pro "in place of" + nomen "name, noun" (see name (n.)). A loan-translation of Greek antonymia.

A pronoun, however, doesn't stand for a noun but a noun phrase (NP), as stated in *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* by Huddleston, Rodney; Pullum, Geoffrey (CGEL) (Page 1461):

> The traditional term ‘pronoun’ is based on the idea that words of this
> class ‘stand for’ nouns. Traditional grammar does not work with a
> constituent structure model like that assumed in this book, and hence
> does not draw the distinction we do between nouns and NPs. When
> adapted to the present framework, therefore, **the traditional idea is
> that pronouns are words that ‘stand for’ NPs**.

But this, being "the traditional idea", doesn't mean it's safe to say that pronouns stand for NPs, either.

Firstly, pronouns such as *what*, *who*, *I*, and *you* do not stand for any NPs or even any *thing*, because some such pronouns "[fall] outside the scope of anaphora," as CGEL puts it. For example, none of these pronouns stands for anything:

> **What** do **you** want?
>
> **Who** is **he**? (Looking at a man.)
>
> **I** love **you**.

Secondly, pronouns such as "it" can stand for clauses:

> If **he was disappointed by her response** he did not show **it**. [pro-clause] (CGEL page 1463)

At this point, I wonder how continuing to use the term 'pronoun' can be anything but confusing. But CGEL wants to keep the term:

> In the present grammar we retain the traditional category of pronoun,
> but introduce a further category based on the idea of ‘standing for’ –
> the category of **pro-form**.

The literal and obvious meaning arising from the term is so incongruous with what the term purports to refer to that it seriously hinders our understanding of what pronouns actually are.

What I agree with CGEL is that a pronoun is a noun because it acts like one, e.g., acting as a subject, an object, and a predicative complement in a clause, and acting as a head of an NP. And a couple of previous questions received answers agreeing that it is a noun:

[Are pronouns nouns?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/316726/are-pronouns-nouns)

[Pronouns: a word class or a subclass of nouns?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42288/pronouns-a-word-class-or-a-subclass-of-nouns)

Now, if pronouns are to belong to nouns, between common nouns and proper nouns, pronouns seem closer to proper nouns than to common nouns in the sense that they don't take any determiners or, in most cases, any dependents.

Also, while some proper nouns such as *America* and *England* refer to the the same thing regardless of context, other proper nouns such as *Jones* and *Mom* can refer to different things depending on context. If we call the latter proper nouns **ad hoc proper nouns**, can we not use the same term for pronouns or at least consider them as such?

Comment: Too broad for ELU.

Comment: While I'm certainly not in favour of all the recommendations to be found in CGEL (intransitive prepositions being a lumping too far in my opinion), their stance (which is pretty generally held) here seems better than this suggested recategorisation. I'd say a complete overhaul of the situation covering all the presently accepted subclasses of pronouns would be better, but that is a mammoth task. // Would 'England' become an 'ad hoc proper noun' in 'the England of 1755'? 'England were beaten 2-0'?

Comment: John is annoying. I don't like him. How is *John* a noun phrase? Your brother is annoying. I don't like him. Now that qualifies just barely as a noun phrase, but where is the substantial difference?

Comment: @KarlG A noun phrase can consist of a single noun in case you're not aware of it.

Comment: @KarlG Here's an example of an NP consisting of a single noun: _Necessity is the mother of invention._ The subject consists of a single noun _necessity_, which by itself constitutes an NP.

Comment: @JK2: and how does it manage that all on its own without exploding any conventional definition of *phrase*?

Comment: @KarlG That's how CGEL and most recent grammars define an NP. And it's not just recent grammars but also this Oxford dictionary as well, which defines a noun phrase as "a word or group of words containing a noun and functioning in a sentence as subject, object, or prepositional object." https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/noun_phrase

Comment: So what is the distinction between nouns and NPs in the citation above, since it appears that once a noun appears in a grammatical relationship to any other word in any context, it becomes an NP.

Comment: @KarlG Just expand the idea of a phrase to a single word, and everything will be fine. I'm afraid this discussion is beginning to go outside the scope of my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71128/discussion-between-karlg-and-jk2).

Answer (score 2):

You ask:

> Can 'pronouns' be considered ad hoc proper nouns?

While you make an interesting case, I think you're mixing the *meaning* of proper nouns with how they are *used* ("don't take any determiners", etc).

> **Proper noun** *noun*
>   A name used for an individual person, place, or organization, spelled with an initial capital letter, e.g. Jane, London, and Oxfam.
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/proper_noun)

Since pronouns don't always function this way (they aren't even *names*), I don't think it would be appropriate to call them ad hoc *proper* nouns.

Comment: Are you sure that pronouns "aren't even names"? Do you accept the categorization that pronouns belong to nouns? If you do, pronouns have to be names, if you know what I mean.

Comment: @JK2 I'm sure "it" isn't ordinarily a name (cousins to the Addams excluded). By 'name', I don't just mean references (like 'table' or 'she') - I mean labels, like 'America' or 'JK2'. In that sense, pronouns are definitely not names. The notion of 'belonging' to nouns is descriptive, but I don't think it goes far enough to make pronouns names. One could say that adverbs 'belong' to verbs (if I've understood your abstract notion of 'belonging'), but that doesn't make adverbs verbs.

Comment: A "name" is defined by Oxford as "a word or set of words by which a person or thing is known, addressed, or referred to." https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/name According to this definition, I believe that pronouns _are_ names.

Comment: @JK2 I disagree. "The Mona Lisa" would be considered a name. The definition for *name* you referenced might conceivably be stretched to cover the noun *painting* with reference to the same object, but '*it*' would be stretching that definition to breaking point. ...

Comment: @JK2 ... There is an argument that adjectives are really nouns because one can conceivably ask for a "red". I think calling pronouns *proper nouns* has a similar feel - although you can redefine *proper noun* to include pronouns, it waters down the useful distinction between pronouns and proper nouns. It would be preferable (in my opinion) to use a different term to refer to the hypernym of pronouns and proper nouns that excludes nouns that *aren't* proper nouns.

Comment: The very argument of yours that we should look into the _meaning_ rather than the _syntactic properties_ to figure out the parts of speech leads to the confusion that CGEL mentions on page 30 as follows...

Comment: i _I was annoyed at their **rejection** of my proposals._ [noun] ii _I was annoyed that they **rejected** my proposals._ [verb] These have essentially the same meaning, but _rejection_ is a noun and _rejected_ a verb. What enables us to tell that _rejection_ but not _rejected_ belongs to the category of noun is not that _rejection_ denotes a thing while _rejected_ does not, but that they figure in quite different grammatical constructions.

Comment: @JK2 Ah, but what distinguishes nouns from verbs doesn't necessarily define either. By way of analogy: we can tell that a flag is American and not Australian because it has stars in the corner - but that doesn't make China's flag (which also has stars in the corner) American. Likewise, nouns and verbs having different grammatical constructions doesn't make pronouns *proper nouns*.

Comment: I didn't say, let's make pronouns proper nouns. What I'm saying is, the current term 'pronoun' misrepresents what it purports to represent, as abundantly shown in my question, and what the term tries to represent might be better understood by considering it an "ad hoc" proper noun.

Comment: @JK2 I misspoke; my apologies. The last sentence of my previous comment should say "... doesn't make pronouns *proper nouns*, ad hoc or otherwise". Still, I do think your proposal about certain parallels between pronouns and proper nouns has merit and is interesting.